# Are Comics/Novel Question On topic here?

Tags: discussion

I am curious to know are Comics/Novel Question On topic here Like Science Fiction and Fantasy or off topic.

I mean if i ask about a question purely on Comics or Novel ( which have Movies on them too ) then is it on topic or off topic.

Similarly Comic/movie comparison or Novel/movie comparison is on topic or not?

It is just to set up boundaries or to know about site's boundaries .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the site is about *Movies and Television* questions about *comics and novels* are **Off-Topic** here.

Asking questions about a movie **made** from these sources and how they differ (specific differences, not a general difference question) are **on-topic**.

Answer (score 2):

They have this incase you'd interested https://scifi.stackexchange.com/. I see whole bunch of questions related to the comic books and arcs over there.

As long it has something to do with movies/tv shows i mean comic book comparisons and references to movies its on topic

This faq covers scenarios piece by piece and probably would eliminate your doubts https://movies.stackexchange.com/faq